# What is the difference between the two styles of documentation comments in Rust? (/// vs //!)

Tags: rust

The [Rust language doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/comments.html) says the following about documentation comments (emphasis mine):

> Doc comments use `///` instead of `//` [...] There is another style of doc comment, `//!`, to comment containing items (e.g. crates, modules or **functions**), instead of the items following it.

And just to confuse things, the document provides an example using the `///` format to document a **function** (visible via the link, but omitted in the ellipsis, above).

I've seen the two styles used pretty much synonymously before--is there a difference between them in Rust? My searches here and on the interwebs turned up nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key word is **containing**. `//!` comments document the thing that *contains* it:

```
fn foo() {
    //! a super awesome function
    ...
}
```

`///` comments document the thing that *follows* it:

```
/// a super awesome function
fn foo() {
    ...
}
```

The styles are otherwise equivalent. But you can only use `//!` with things that actually *contain* code -- such as crates, modules, and functions -- so that's why the doc calls out those three as examples.

Answer (score 6):

This code:

```
/// I am referring to the next item
mod foo {
    fn bar() {}
}
```

Is equivalent (modulo the one word difference) to this code:

```
mod foo {
    //! I am referring to the enclosing item
    fn bar() {}
}
```

Both times, the doc comment belongs to the `mod` declaration.

---

- **`///`** documents the **next** item
- **`//!`** documents the **enclosing** item

Note, that usually you would only use `///`. Documenting anything other than modules with `//!` is bad style and should be avoided. You always want to use `///` *except* if you want to document a module (including the root-module/crate); then it's fine to write the documentation inside of that module with `//!`.

Comment: This is a better answer given that it distinguishes between module comment and non-module comment